# Bash Zip Script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, zip

I have written a script which (in theory) should zip all the contents of a folder (including subfolders and what not).

However, when it's ran, it just includes one folder.

Could you please help.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# pull the svn files
cd /path/to/my/svn/folder
svn update

#Zip (tar gzip) up the folder
zip -r updateZip trunk/*

sleep 1


USERNAME="******"
PASSWORD="******"
SERVER="127.0.0.1"

# local directory to pickup zip file
FILE="updateZip.zip"

# remote server directory to upload backup
BACKUPDIR="my/backup/dir/"

# login to remote server
ftp -n -i $SERVER <<EOF
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
cd $BACKUPDIR
mput $FILE
quit
EOF
```

Comment: Tar the directory and THEN zip it

Comment: @Alfabravo That should not be neccessary.

Comment: I could use rsync, but that's not the point. I have been instructed to do it this way. :/

Comment: @nfechner I think it fails at some point because of some odd error. Just giving OP a fast solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zip (tar gzip) up the folder

```
zip -r updateZip trunk/*
```

If you want a tar.gz, try

```
$ tar zcvf updateZip.tar.gz trunk/*
```

Comment: If the comment is correct, `zip -r` is the wrong command in the first place. If you really do want zip, try with just `trunk` rather than the wildcard `trunk/*`.

Comment: I've tried all of this and none of it seems to work correctly. I know this is a real pain in the ass but it's really bugging me now. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Linux sucks everywhere. What's the file here ? Will the folder be packed or just it's contents ? what does -r stands for, what the difference to -R ? What is "updateZip" ?

Answer (score 0):

To zip up a folder and all its contents in a g-zipped tarball, simply enter

```
tar czf trunk.tar.gz trunk/
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but it doesnt work. I've tried so much crap now I'm getting frustrated with it :P

Comment: Is `trunk` a symlink? If yes, try also `trunk/.`